# Conditional query with WhereBetween in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've got the following controller function section for a little search block form:

```
    $manifests = DB::table('carrier_manifests')
        ->join('customers', 'carrier_manifests.carrierOrigin', '=', 'customers.id')
        ->select('carrier_manifests.*', 'customers.customer_name')          
        ->where([
                    ['manifestNumber', 'LIKE', '%' . $manifest . '%'],
                    ['originTerminal','LIKE','%' . $terminal . '%'],
                    ['carrierOrigin', $direction[0], $direction[1]],
                ])
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->orderBy('dateUnloaded', 'DESC')
        ->whereBetween('dateUnloaded', [$startDate, $endDate])
        ->limit(100)
        ->get();
```

Every part of it works correctly except for one section, the `whereBetween`, because of a workflow necessity, sometimes the `dateUnloaded` in the clause is not filled in for every `carrier_manifest`, so that means if the `dateUnloaded` field is empty, it will be left out of the search results.

Are there any suggestions for how to include those results missing the `dateUnloaded`?

Comment: Do you have used `created_at` and `updated_at` columns ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do a nested `where()` for the null values or between like:

```
$manifests = DB::table('carrier_manifests')
    ->join('customers', 'carrier_manifests.carrierOrigin', '=', 'customers.id')
    ->select('carrier_manifests.*', 'customers.customer_name')          
    ->where([
                ['manifestNumber', 'LIKE', '%' . $manifest . '%'],
                ['originTerminal','LIKE','%' . $terminal . '%'],
                ['carrierOrigin', $direction[0], $direction[1]],
            ])
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->orderBy('dateUnloaded', 'DESC')
    ->where(function($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
        return $query->whereBetween('dateUnloaded', [$startDate, $endDate])
            ->orWhereNull('dateUnloaded');
    })
    ->limit(100)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

So from what I have understood is that `dateUnloaded` may or may not be provided to the query.

In such a case you can use the `when` method of laravel

Example taken from laravel docs
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->when($role, function ($query) use ($role) {
                    return $query->where('role_id', $role);
                })
                ->get();
```

Here you can see that if `$role` is present then only the query will be executed otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This...

```
 $manifests = DB::table('carrier_manifests')
        ->join('customers', 'carrier_manifests.carrierOrigin', '=', 'customers.id')
        ->select('carrier_manifests.*', 'customers.customer_name')          
        ->where([
                    ['manifestNumber', 'LIKE', '%' . $manifest . '%'],
                    ['originTerminal','LIKE','%' . $terminal . '%'],
                    ['carrierOrigin', $direction[0], $direction[1]],
                ])
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->orderBy('dateUnloaded', 'DESC')
        ->where(function($q) use ($startDate,$endDate){
                   if($endDate !="" && $startDate !=""){
                         $q->whereBetween('dateUnloaded', [$startDate, $endDate]);
                   }

                   return $q;  
         })
        ->limit(100)
        ->get();
```